# I'm trying to change my directory on cmd from js to python, how can I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my directory on cmd is C:\users\mike\desktop\learn Programming\JS-Basics.
But I'm trying to change it to pythonDev\myprogram.py, how can I go about it?

Comment: cd <full path here without brackets>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
os.chdir(“your\\desired\\complete\\folder\\path”)
```

Remember to import `os` module first